# How can I install Ubuntu on boot up

Tags: boot, partitioning, dvd

I down loaded Ubuntu to DVD, not my hard drive which doesn't have enough space.  I placed the DVD in the drive and shut down.  On start up it did not launch the DVD but took me to the log in choice:  windows or ubuntu.  This DVD is called ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso and does have a file on it iso linux.  It is nearly a gig in size.  Is there no way to boot off this?  Or how can I get a fresh install and get rid of my windows partition?  I appreciate comments thus far, but none of the suggestions has worked.

Comment: What do you mean with "downloading Ubuntu to DVD"? You need to download the file and then burn the .iso to a DVD or create a live USB with it.

Comment: I mean I right clicked on 'Download Now' and saved the whole thing to exterior drive then to DVD.  It is called .iso.  Are you saying there is an iso file in that 1 gig I down loaded?

Comment: How did you burn the DVD? Did you simply copy the iso to the DVD or burn the image to the DVD?

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the ISO to your DVD, not burn the ISO as a data file. Most burning suites will have an option like `create dvd from disc image`, that is what you'll need to choose, then browse for the ISO, insert a blank DVD, and click burn. You will then be able to boot the DVD, and install Ubuntu.